# Are there unitary transformations on $S(\mathbb{R})$ other than the Fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-analysis

Pretty much the title says it all. For $f$, $g$ in $S(\mathbb{R})$ one has

$$
\langle f, g \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)g(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{f}(k)\hat{g}(k) dk = \langle \hat{f},\hat{g} \rangle        \quad \quad (1)
$$

where $\hat{f}$ is the Fourier transform of $f$.

Are there other function transforms with the property (1) above? If there are, is there some kind of generalized Fourier transform that encompasses them all? If there aren't, could you provide a link to the proof?

What is a good reference to read about this subject?

*Edit 1:*  As **Yiorgos** showed below, it is rather trivial to find a host of $T$s such that

$$\langle f,g\rangle = \langle Tf, Tg \rangle \,. $$

However, all these $T$s satisfy that there exists an $n$ such that

$$T^n = 1 \,. \quad\quad (2)$$

This is also true for the Fourier transform. A $T$ that does not satisfy (2) and still preserves the scalar product is simply

$$Tf = f(x+a) \,.$$

Are there any other examples of $T$ that do not satisfy $T^n = 1$? I would be specifically interested in $T$s that, in analogy with the Fourier transform, do NOT preserve the "shape" of $f$.

*Edit 2:* Maybe I should create another question given that the original one has been answered.

Anyhow, as Yiorgos points out, one can find unitary transformations $T(\alpha)$ in general parametrized by an infinite number of phases which I collectively represent here as $\alpha$. These $T$ do not satisfy $T^n = 1$.

On the other hand, any two such $T$ commute:

$$T(\alpha_1) \cdot T(\alpha_2) = T(\alpha_2) \cdot T(\alpha_1) $$

The new question is then, does there exist a family of unitary transformations on $S(\mathbb{R})$ as above - say parametrized by some parameters collectively denoted as $\beta$ - such that $T(\beta_1)$ and $T(\beta_2)$ do not commute for some values of $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$?

Comment: They do not have to commute, as orthogonal matrices (even 2x2) do not in general commute.

Comment: I don't understand, are you saying that your $T$s - the last ones you defined - do not commute?

Comment: The last ones in my answer do commute, as they are basically infinite diagonal matrices.

Comment: Exactly. I don't see how to generalize to noncommutative $T$s but I'll think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of them, i.e.,
$$
(Tf)(x)=f(-x),
$$
$$
(Tf)=-f,
$$
Take $g\in \mathscr{S}(\mathbb R)$, with $\langle g,g\rangle=1$, and define
$$
Tf=f-2\langle f,g\rangle g.
$$

Also, take $g_1,g_2\in\mathscr S(\mathbb R)$, with
$$
\langle g_1,g_1\rangle=\langle g_2,g_2\rangle=1\quad\text{and}\quad\langle g_1,g_2\rangle=0.
$$
Define
$$
T_af=f-\langle f,g_1\rangle g_1-\langle f,g_2\rangle g_2 \\+(\cos a\langle f,g_1\rangle+\sin a\langle f,g_2\rangle)g_1+(-\sin a\langle f,g_1\rangle+\cos a\langle f,g_2\rangle)g_2.
$$
Clearly $T^n_a=T_{na}$, and if $2\pi/a$ irrational, then $T^n\ne I$, for anny $n$.

Now, more generally, if $\{e_n(x)\}_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset\mathscr S(\mathbb R)$, is an orthnormal basis of $L^2(\mathbb R)$, then
$$
u=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\langle u,e_n\rangle e_n.
$$
Let $a_n\in\{-1,1\}$ (in general $a_n\in\mathbb C$ and $|a_n|=1$) and define
$$
Tu=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}a_n\langle u,e_n\rangle e_n.
$$
Clearly $T$ is also unitary and
$$
(Tu)(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}a_n\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty u(y)\,\bar e_n(y)\,dy\right)e_n(x)
=\int_{-\infty}^\infty K(x,y)\,u(y)\,dy,
$$
where
$$
K(x,y)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}a_n\, e_n(x)\,\bar e_n(y).
$$

Comment: Thanks. I would like to read general results about such transforms. Could you provide me with a good reference?

Comment: To be more specific, I would like to know whether (or how) some standard results from the theory of Lie groups (unitary ones in particular) can be ported to such transforms. The Schwartz space would be analogous to the vector space under which the group element in a specific representation - the analogue of the transform - would act.

Comment: To be even more specific. These transformations you post here, all satisfy that there exists an $n$ such that $T^n = 1$. Of course, the Fourier transform also has this property. So, are there unitary transformations on $S(\mathbb{R})$ that  do not satisfy $T^n = 1$ for some integer $n$? I will edit the original question.

Comment: See edited version

Comment: Ok, so it seems I can produce infitely many such transformations making use of some orthonormal set of functions like your $g_i$ above. Sorry to keep going on about this, it might be better if you provided a reference but anyhow. Do you know any $T(x,y)$ - other than Fourier - such that $Tf = \int T(x,y) f(y) dy$ is unitary?

Comment: See new version of the answer.

Comment: I am going to accept the answer because it reallys is an answer to my original question and it has taken you a lot of time. However, these transformations are still not what I am most interested in. In particular, they also satisfy $T^2 = 1$ when $a_n \in \{ 1, -1\}$. It is my fault, the original question was very vague. I am editing once more the original message...

Comment: Please, see new version of the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Upon reflection, I suspect that the question may not quite be the one intended.

That is, in my interpretation, the question is about maps $T$ of the Schwartz space to itself which preserve the $L^2$ norm. Such $T$ extends by continuity to a map $L^2\to L^2$ which preserves $L^2$-norm and stabilizes the Schwartz space.

Taking that as the genuine question, recall that (for example) the so-called "quantum harmonic oscillator" (operator) $H=-\Delta+x^2$ (with suitable discussion of self-adjoint extension...) has an orthonormal basis of eigenfunctions in $L^2$, of the form $u_n=$ hermite-polynomial times suitable Gaussian. These eigenfunctions are also in the Schwartz space.

Maps such as "interchange $u_{n_1}$ and $u_{n_2}$" are "unitary" in the sense of the question, and are continuous in the (projective limit) topology on Schwartz functions. Certainly not all such (finite) permutations of the $u_n$'s commute...

EDIT: Yes, these finite permutations are of finite order. Such permutations are obviously also continuous on the Schwartz space.

In fact, a one-sided shift $T(\sum_n c_n\cdot u_n)=\sum_n c_n\cdot u_{n+1}$ is unitary on $L^2$, stabilizes the Schwartz space, and is continuous on the Schwartz space (though not stabilizing individual Sobolev-like spaces). These operators are not of finite order, and do not commute with the finite permutations.